# Positivity of Conditional Expectation

Tags: probability, probability-theory

This might be a very easy to answer question: Let $(\Omega,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$ be a probability space and $\mathcal F'$ a $\sigma$-subalgebra of $\mathcal F$. Let $X:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb R$ be a measurable function such that $\mathbb P(X>0)>0.$ Is it true that $\mathbb P(E_\mathbb P[X\mid\mathcal F']>0)>0$?

Comment: What's $\mathbb{Q}$? The restriction of $\mathbb{P}$ to $\mathcal{F}'$...? Or should it read $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{Q})$ instead of $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$?

Comment: Sorry, that should be a $\mathbb P$ instead of $\mathbb Q$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Let $X'=\mathbb E[X\mid \mathcal F']$. If $X$ is independent of $\mathcal F'$ and if $\mathbb E[X]\leqslant0$ then $\mathbb P[X'\gt0]=0$. This may happen while $\mathbb P[X\gt0]\gt0$.

If one adds the condition that $\mathbb P[X\lt0]=0$, then $\mathbb P[X'\gt0]=0$ is impossible. To see why, note that $X\geqslant0$ almost surely implies that $X'\geqslant0$ almost surely hence $\mathbb P[X'\gt0]=0$ would imply that $X'=0$ almost surely, which is impossible since $\mathbb E[X']=\mathbb E[X]$ and $\mathbb E[X]\gt0$ because $X\geqslant0$ almost surely and $\mathbb P[X\gt0]\gt0$.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not. Note that we can choose $\mathcal{F}'$ as the trivial $\sigma$-algebra, then $$\mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{P}}(X \mid \mathcal{F}')= \mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{P}}(X)$$

For a random variable $X$ such that $\mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{P}}X \leq 0$, $\mathbb{P}(X>0)>0$ we have $$\mathbb{P}(\mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{P}}(X \mid \mathcal{F}')>0)=0$$

Comment: ok, but in my case I have additionally that $\mathbb P(X\geq 0)=1$ and with this additional assumption your counter example would not work, right?

Comment: @AndyTeich No, but you didn't mention this assumption before.

Comment: yes, sorry. I thought that the more general question will also answer my special case...